# ttorrent library HttpResponseMessage error

Tags: java, android, bittorrent

I'm trying to use ttorrent library to create torrent app for android.
I'm having some issue.

> 05-29 23:07:23.388: E/AndroidRuntime(3681): FATAL EXCEPTION: bt-announce(..393337)
>
> 05-29 23:07:23.388: E/AndroidRuntime(3681): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 05-29 23:07:23.388: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):    at com.turn.ttorrent.common.protocol.http.HTTPAnnounceResponseMessage.parse(HTTPAnnounceResponseMessage.java:105)
>
> 05-29 23:07:23.388: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):    at com.turn.ttorrent.common.protocol.http.HTTPTrackerMessage.parse(HTTPTrackerMessage.java:51)
>
> 05-29 23:07:23.388: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):    at com.turn.ttorrent.client.announce.HTTPTrackerClient.announce(HTTPTrackerClient.java:124)
>
> 05-29 23:07:23.388: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):    at com.turn.ttorrent.client.announce.Announce.run(Announce.java:224)
>
> 05-29 23:07:23.388: E/AndroidRuntime(3681):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

```
public static HTTPAnnounceResponseMessage parse(ByteBuffer data)
    throws IOException, MessageValidationException {
    BEValue decoded = BDecoder.bdecode(data);
    if (decoded == null) {
        throw new MessageValidationException(
            "Could not decode tracker message (not B-encoded?)!");
    }

    Map<String, BEValue> params = decoded.getMap();

    try {
        List<Peer> peers;

        try {
            // First attempt to decode a compact response, since we asked
            // for it.
            peers = toPeerList(params.get("peers").getBytes());
        } catch (InvalidBEncodingException ibee) {
            // Fall back to peer list, non-compact response, in case the
            // tracker did not support compact responses.
            peers = toPeerList(params.get("peers").getList());
        }

        return new HTTPAnnounceResponseMessage(data,
            params.get("interval").getInt(),
            params.get("complete").getInt(),
            params.get("incomplete").getInt(),
            peers);
    } catch (InvalidBEncodingException ibee) {
        throw new MessageValidationException("Invalid response " +
            "from tracker!", ibee);
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        throw new MessageValidationException("Invalid peer " +
            "in tracker response!", uhe);
    }
```

There is no keys such "interval" or "complete" or "inclomplete" is params. There is two keys "peers" and "min interval".

As far as I get it After i call Client method download it requested some information from tracker and then tryied to parse this information. And that's where the error is.

So, the question is why is it so? Is it error in the library or Did I something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the question?

Please, edit your question and add more details.

Ideally include a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Add to your question a link to a torrent file that is exhibiting this error.
How are you building ttorrent?

Confirm that the error you are seeing occurs when run from Android and does not occur in plain Java.

You can use git to get the ttorrent code from github or click the button on the github project to download a zip.

ttorrent uses maven.   If you fetch the dependencies manually you may not get the correct versions.
You should import the code into Eclipse as a maven project.
Eclipse -> File -> ...Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project

In the navigator pane.  Find the ttorrent project and right-click choose Run As -> Maven Build ...
For the goal type in "package" and click "Run".

I started with the ttorrent example client and added the path to a known good [Ubuntu 13.04 torrent file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent) and also a directory to save into.

I ran the code in the debugger and ttorrent functioned correctly.  It began downloading Ubuntu without throwing exceptions or printing error messages.

At the line you listed I see that the params map has four entries ("interval", "complete", "peers", "incomplete").

Here is the client code I used:

```
public class ClientTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {    
        try {
            SharedTorrent fromFile =
            SharedTorrent.fromFile(
            new File("j:/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent"),
            new File("j:/td"));
            Client client =
                new Client(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), fromFile);
            client.download();
            client.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, how exactly you've "started from ttorrent example".
Because after I've downloaded files, I've created new project in Eclipse. Then I've copy-pasted all files to my src directory.
Then downloaded all jars such as simple framework, commons.io and so on.
And I can see error in TrackerService class.

response.setText("Not Found");
 gives the error. Resoponse just don't have such method at all.